# SmartGit takes long time to load repository

Tags: git, smartgit

I have a big git repository. `git status` still returns immediately, though. However, SmartGit takes several minutes to load the repository.

I suspect this is because it asks the FS to track every single file in the repository.

According to [this website](https://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG/System+Properties), there is a setting called `smartgit.filemonitor.enabled`. So I wrote the line

```
smartgit.filemonitor.enabled=false
```

into `~/.smartgit/7.1/smartgit.properties` and restarted SmartGit. Nothing changed and I wasn't able to find anything other than that via Google.

Do I have to use a different syntax or is there a different approach?

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit with the 4.4.0-24-generic kernel and SmartGit 7.1.3 running on Java version 1.7.0_80-b15. The repository is in my encrypted home repository (ecryptfs; standard Ubuntu home folder encryption) on an ext4 partition.

Comment: This isn't what you are asking, but there might be another approach here. If you don't need all the project history, there is a --depth flag to clone that can limit how much information it fetches. If you can get away with just recent commits and people aren't cloning off of you, then maybe this would help speed things up for you. Consider this with --[no-]single-branch as well.

Comment: Did you already check out https://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG/Performance+Tuning?

Comment: @DavidN I use this repo alone and there aren't many commits (only 206). That can't be the problem. I yesterday added 2'691 files totaling 9.4 GB which tripled the time I have to wait every time I open the repo with SmartGit.

Comment: @mstrap Thank you, but that didn't help. 1.: I set it to 10 GiB. SmartGit isn't using nearly as much, though, and there is no difference. 2.: My repo is on my local drive. It even is an SSD from which my laptop can read with more than 500 MB/s according to the benchmarking tool which comes with Ubuntu. 3.: The repo isn't accessed via a symlink and there are no symlinks in the parts of it that are tracked by git. 4.: I disabled all background processes. No difference in startup time. 5.: Same as `1.`. 6.: Has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: I'd recommend to create periodical thread dumps and send to smartgit@syntevo.com: https://www.syntevo.com/doc/display/SG/Periodical+Thread+Dumps

Comment: @mstrap Thank you! I wrote them an email.

Comment: Also try clean up option in `Local -> clean up`

Comment: @Arashsoft Thanks for the try but I always keep my repos cleaned up. That's not the problem.